# Wireless router simultaneously dropping multiple computers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, troubleshooting, internet-connection

I've read several articles online as well as

- [Wireless internet router keeps dropping out](https://superuser.com/questions/421904/wireless-internet-router-keeps-dropping-out)
- [Computer "loses" connection to wireless router intermittently](https://superuser.com/questions/523200/computer-loses-connection-to-wireless-router-intermittently)

My scenario is as follows:

- When connection is lost, a yellow sign appears over the Wifi systray icon, indicating a connection to the router but with no Internet access.
- When connection is lost, I've confirmed with roommates that they've lost theirs too.
- I've used Meraki Wifi Stumbler to see what channels other networks are using, but we're already on the least crowded one, with 2 other routers on channel 6.
- That's for the 2.4 GHz network, though. The Arris router I have also broadcasts in 5 GHz, **which drops out too, simultaneously**, which I think means this can't be related to crowded channels.
- I don't see any option for a "protected mode" on this router's setttings pages.
- I don't see anything in the event log that correlates with the time that the connections are dropped, besides the computers reconnecting / renewing the lease.

What else can I check? Here's a screenshot of the router's system status page:

[image]

I am probably imagining it, but sometimes it feels like it occurs when I initiate multiple requests at once, like opening a set of links, all in new tabs, or when starting several torrents. I'm guessing HTTP requests can't have any relation to TCP/IP / connection-level issues, though.

---

### Edit for @Tyson

[image]

Comment: I doubt this is your wifi dropping out. It's likely the whole internet connection.  You didn't mention if you have any hard wired connections, or what happens with lights on the router and/or modem during these events.

Comment: From your public IP address it looks like you have TWC cable internet.  See if you can get the modems interface at 192.168.100.1 the credentials should be user admin and the password is password or admin. Post a screenshot of the signal levels.

Comment: @Tyson - Edited my post. And you're right—I didn't try to see if it was TWC—so next time my connection drops out (it happens every 15-30 minutes), I'll go check the lights.

Comment: Your downstream power levels are high.  That number should be closer to 0. (0 being perfect but it will never be exactly 0).  The problem is on the coax side, next time it happens I bet you will find the online light off.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Tyson. Unfortunately, the Internet LED was solid as usual after the Internet dropped—I checked three times today. The thing is though, when the Internet drops, I can always disconnect from the network and reconnect immediately, and it's good to go. (But if I don't disconnect, it will just stay broken for a while—minutes, at least.) You might be right that the Internet is going out, but perhaps it recovers so quickly that I can't detect the LED going off. Is that possible?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that after the Internet drops, when I look at the lights, I see the 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz LEDs blinking at a regular interval in _perfect_ sync for a while (more than ten seconds, but haven't really counted). Normally, those LEDs indicate activity and blink at erratic rates.

Comment: Does the event log on the arris admin page give any clues?

Comment: Oh wow... Your corrected packet count is way high too...The modem shows it's been up 56 days but those numbers are gigantic.  Corrected means that there was a correctable error, that's less severe than the error to the right collectables.  I'd say you have noise on your cable line and occasionally it's knocking you off.  It still a puzzle tho why disconnecting and reconnecting the wifi seems to help.